# Docker Swarm: deploy containers on Worker node

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, docker-swarm-mode

I am trying to deploy the application on multiple instances.
On master node, I used these bunch of commands:

- `docker swarm init`
- `docker network create --attachable --driver overlay fabric`
- `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-org2.yaml fabric`

And the service was deployed on master node and is running properly.

Now I have another compose file named: `docker-compose-orderer.yaml` Which I want to deploy on other AWS instance.

I used the following command on `worker node`:

- `docker swarm join --token SWMTKN-1-29jg0j594eluoy8g86dniy3opax0jphhe3a4w3hjuvglekzt1b-525ene2t4297pgpxp5h5ayf89 <IP>:2377`
- `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-org1.yaml fabric`

It command `docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose-org1.yaml fabric` says `this node is not a swarm manager. Use "docker swarm init" or "docker swarm join" to connect this node to swarm and try again`

Does anyone knows how to deploy the compose file in worker node?

Any help/suggestion would be appreciated.

**Update 1:**

Worker node joined swarm manager successfully.

```
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS              AVAILABILITY        MANAGER STATUS      ENGINE VERSION
qz9y7p1ba3prp23xtuv3uo2dk     ip-172-31-18-206    Ready               Active                                  18.06.1-ce
no97mrg6f7eftbbeu86xg88d9 *   ip-172-31-40-235    Ready               Active              Leader              18.06.1-ce
```

Comment: yes I can see the node. Check updated details

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you must apply all `docker service` and `docker stack` commands on manager nodes. it will deploy automatically the containers on less used nodes. when you want to explicit deploy a container on a specific node, you must tag this node and work with constraints.

Comment: @paskl connect your local docker daemon with the docker daemon of a manager node or ssh into a manager node and run your command there.